# VBA to apply formula to column and then color cells based on formula results

Tags: vba, colors, formula

So I have a program that loops through all the excel files in a folder and applies a formula to a cell. That works. I also want to color all the cells yellow if the formula comes back true. That works. When I put them together all the cells return False and are shaded Red. But when I run the color code standalone it works. My guess is that the formula isn't applied by the time it does the coloring loop.

Any ideas on how to make sure that the formula is applied before the For Loop?

```
    lastRow = wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        wb.Worksheets(1).Range("H2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=NOT(ISNA(MATCH(RC[-6],'\\netdrv00\pcps\PlannerReports\BSO Planners\New Automation Line\[_MyDataFilePrep.xlsm]CarrierDB'!C5:C5,0)))"
        Range("H2").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:H" & lastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault

    For j = wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(j, "H") = True Then
            wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(j, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            Else: wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(j, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                End If

    Next j
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the `For...` line and wait a couple of seconds before proceeding does it work as expected?  You might be better off using Conditional Formatting so the color always matches the formula result.